# Kustomize and ArgoCD - Need to update a NetworkPolicy Object during PreSync and PostSync of ArgoCD Sync

Tags: kubernetes, argocd, kustomize, kubernetes-networkpolicy

There is a NetworkPolicy Object which I want to update during Argo's PreSync using annotation `argocd.argoproj.io/hook: PreSync` and update it again during PostSync using annotation `argocd.argoproj.io/hook: PostSync`.

How to include both these operations because kustomize build will finally keep only one operation?

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

To make kustomize builds consider both operation presync and postsync while updating a networkpolicy object, you can use the `patch field` in the `kustomization.yaml` file. This allows you to specify patches that should be applied before or after the sync operation.

```
apiVersion: kustomize.config.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Kustomization
resources:
- networkpolicy.yaml
patches:
- path: patch-presync.yaml
  target:
    kind: NetworkPolicy
    name: my-network-policy
  options:
    create: true
- path: patch-postsync.yaml
  target:
    kind: NetworkPolicy
    name: my-network-policy


apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: NetworkPolicy
metadata:
  name: my-network-policy
spec:
  ingress:
  - from:
      - podSelector:
          matchLabels:
            app.kubernetes.io/name: nginx
```

You can find more information in a [blog by Karim Elatov](https://elatov.github.io/2021/08/using-kustomize/#patching) , If you want to patch multiple objects then follow this [doc](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kustomize/blob/master/examples/patchMultipleObjects.md).

Comment: Hi Sai thanks for the reply. I checked this one. Before Argo Sync when kustomize build command is run, it will create a single NetworkPolicy Yaml file with only postSync configuration. PreSync is not present that single file.